# unmount for extundelete causing issues

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-recovery

I have a LAMP stack on DigitalOcean and one of my ex employees went ahead and deleted all files under `www` folder. I read online and tried using [`extundelete`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/extundelete.1.html) to recover the folder. But one of the steps to using extundelete was unmounting the disk. Since my disk was showing an error that it was busy I used lazy unmount.

Now none of the disk commands are working. Also when I use `extundelete` the error message shows

```
"stat "/dev/vda1/": No such file or directory"
```

System is not rebooting and all commands show they can't open `/proc`

Additionally my `ssh` from terminal on my local machine has stopped working. Please help in helping me recover my machine to a working state again and using `extundelete`.